# Clang-Tidy: check number of lines in a function

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Can you please help me with how to check CPP files in a project for functions exceeding 'n' number of lines using Clang-Tidy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`readability-function-size`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-function-size.html) check and set the `LineThreshold` parameter to your `n` value.